# Show all records with a connection of any distance for given ID

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with data similar to the data below:

| RecID1 | RecID2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 8 |
| 1 | 9 |

I would like a query that if given an ID of say 1 would return the following rows:

| RecID1 | RecID2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 9 |

I would like to get the results of any rows of records that related to each other.  Since 1 has the child of 2 and 2 has a parent of 5 they would be related even though they both do not have the same parent.

So far this is the code I have come up with and have had no luck in getting the results I am looking for.

```
    create table testtable (RecID1 int, RecID2 int)

    insert into testtable values (1,2)
    insert into testtable values (3,1)
    insert into testtable values (5,2)
    insert into testtable values (8,7)
    insert into testtable values (4,5)
    insert into testtable values (6,8)
    insert into testtable values (1,9);

WITH parent AS (
        SELECT recid1
        FROM testtable
        WHERE recid1 = 1 or recid2=1
    ), tree AS (
        SELECT x.RecID1, x.RecID2
        FROM testtable x
        INNER JOIN parent ON x.RecID1 = parent.RecID1 or x.RecID2 = parent.RecID1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT y.RecID1, y.RecID2
        FROM testtable y
        INNER JOIN tree t ON y.RecID1 = t.RecID2
    )
    SELECT RecID1, RecID2
    FROM tree group by RecID1,RecID2
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The sample data is helpful.  But what have you tried?

Comment: The same query you used for the first result + `where RecID1 < 6` :-)

Comment: If there can be only 1 parent and 1 child, then you can just do a self join on the table.  If there can be more you would need to check out recursion/ctes

Comment: So far this is the code I have come up with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5580e/1  I have not been able to get the full results I am looking for.  Also, there will be the possibility for more than 1 parent and or child.

Comment: I feel like you data is incomplete here. How does the row with a `RecID1` of `5` relate?As I read your data `2` is a "child" of `1` but also of `5`, but `1` and `5` aren't a parent/child of the other; they're just both "parents" of `2`.

Comment: Your sample code should not be in a sql fiddle.  It should be in your question.  You can replace your existing tables with your insert statements in the fiddle.  Together with your attempt and a little more explanation of what exactly you're trying to accomplish, and you've got a well formed question.

Comment: Your question title is a little off from what you want.  The question implies just ancestors and descendants.  But you want all horizontal relations (siblings, cousins, xth-cousins) and diagonal relations (nieces, uncles, great aunts, etc) as well.  Maybe "Show all records with a connection of any distance for given ID"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an atomic query is not necessary, then when you traverse the tree you can store the nodes you've visited into a table variable.  Then when you don't add any more nodes to the table, you're done and you can query `testtable` for any rows that have a visited node.

Create a table to store the nodes you've visited:

```
declare @seed int = 1; -- user passed parameter

declare @hits table (value int)
insert @hits select @seed;
```

Traverse the tree, so long as you keep getting new hits:

```
while @@rowcount > 0 

    insert      @hits

    select      
    distinct    ap.value
    from        @testtable t
    cross apply (values (t.RecID1),(t.RecID2)) ap (value)
    where       exists (
                    select  0
                    from    @hits h 
                    where   h.value in (t.RecID1, t.RecID2)
                )

    except      -- we only want new hits, or else @@rowcount won't reach 0
    select      value 
    from        @hits;
```

Output any row that has a visited value:

```
select      *
from        @testtable t
where       exists (
                select  0
                from    @hits h
                where   h.value in (t.RecID1, t.RecID2)
            );
```